# How to check if an object produced by zip() is empty?

Tags: python

If I have lists like these:

```
transactions = ['001','002','003']
transaction_dates = ['01-01-2019','01-02-2019','01-03-2019']
transaction_amounts = ['27.00','35.00','36.00']
```

And I use zip like this

```
results = zip(transactions,transaction_dates,transaction_amounts)
```

How do I tell if `results` is empty?

Comment: But `results` will never be empty in this case. The only case where `results` can be "empty" (in quotes because it will never be "empty", but an empty generator) is if at least one of the lists is empty.

Comment: Give us example data that would make `results` empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific task I would suggest defining a function and calling the `next` method of the iterator returned by `zip` wrapped with a `try`/`expect` to catch the `StopIteration` warning:

```
def is_empty(i):
    try:
        next(i)
        return False
    except StopIteration:
        return True
```

---

```
transactions = ['001','002','003']
transaction_dates = ['01-01-2019','01-02-2019','01-03-2019']
transaction_amounts = ['27.00','35.00','36.00']

is_empty(zip(transactions,transaction_dates,transaction_amounts))
# False
```